# read localization_en.properties file to Map in java

Tags: java, xml, sap-commerce-cloud

The definition in the localization file is as follows.

```
type.ProductQuestionCategory.code.name=Code
type.ProductQuestionCategory.name.name=Name
```

How can I put these definitions in the map as key values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Properties for reading localization or properties files like below. Properties is based on Map.

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
final InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("localization_en.properties");
try {
    properties.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```